# What if the Euler Lagrange equation yields a 'trivial' answer

Tags: classical-mechanics

The example I'm doing gives an equation $$L(y, y') = \frac{y'}{y}$$

then $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = -\frac{y'}{y^2}$$
and $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} = \frac{1}{y}$$
... $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{y} = -\frac{y'}{y^2}$$

substituting into the Euler Lagrange $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}$$ then yields $$-\frac{y'}{y^2} = -\frac{y'}{y^2}$$

Does this mean that any differentiable function $y$ is a solution to the Euler-Lagrange equation for that Lagrangian??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that
$$
\mathcal{L}=\int_a^b L\big(y(t),y'(t)\big)\,dt
=\int_a^b\frac{y'(t)}{y(t)}\,dt=\big[\ln y(t)\big]_a^b=\ln y(b)-\ln y(a)
$$
is independent of the path, and hence, all paths are stationary.

Comment: very good... thanks a lot

Comment: I am not completely understanding how this is "path independent"... this will give you a different answer if $y(t) = t^2$ versus $y(t) = t$.  What do you mean by "path independent" @EinarRodland?

Comment: @Sother It depends only on the end-points, $y(a)$ and $y(b)$, not on the path between them. In the Lagrange formalism, you fix the end-points and find the path that minimises $\mathcal{L}$, but in this case all paths are minimal.

Comment: I see.  So, it "path independent" CAN still depend on the function $y$, but it just doesn't depend on what happens BETWEEN $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @Sother: That's right.