# When the Euler-Lagrange equation reduces to 0=0

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I've gotten the functional $$\int_a^b(y^2+2xyy')dx$$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions.  Applying the Euler-Lagrange equation I get:

$$0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}= 2y+2xy' -\frac{d}{dx}[2xy] = 2y+2xy'-[2y+2xy']=0$$

So this just gives me $0=0$.  Have I done something wrong or does this mean that *every* curve is a stationary curve?  If it's the latter, what's the reason for this functional being path independent (I thought that only happened when the functional is indepedent of $y'$)?

Comment: Similar situation: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191935/what-if-the-euler-lagrange-equation-yields-a-trivial-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( xy^2 \right) = y^2 + 2xyy'.
$$
Hence
$$
\int_a^b \left( y^2 + 2xyy' \right) \, dx = b y(b)^2 - a y(a)^2.
$$

Comment: Since the resulting integral only depends on $a$, $b$, $y(a)$, and $y(b)$, then does that mean it is "path independent"? @Siminore?